# How to schedule yum-cron to run on Centos Monthly in order to automate monthly server updates

Tags: server, cron, centos7, yum

I would like to automate CentOS7 server updates. According to the internet it is possible by installing yum-cron and editing the `/etc/yum/yum-cron.conf` file. However, I don't see how I can schedule this to run on a monthly basis. I have tried scheduling it in anacrontab, but it does not seem to work(nothing happens). The only time it appears to work is when I add the same settings in the `/etc/cron.daily/0yum-daily.cron`file, but again not sure on how to get this to run monthly instead of daily. If I need to alter crontab what would be the command to run yum-cron once a month?

Answer (score 0):

You can add settings inside directory `/etc/cron.monthly/`